How to search with whitespace with Azure AI Search filter with Lucene Syntax
I am using Azure Search and azure.search.documents.SearchOptions
I have this which works
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
    .setFilter("search.ismatch('.*golden.*', 'description', 'full', 'all')");

Above gives me the results for if the description contains the word "golden" anywhere.
But if I try to have it search for multiple words, then it does not work. I'll use the word "golden rod" as an example, where I want to find any description that has the string "golden rod" anywhere.
What I've tried:

search.ismatch('.*golden rod.*', 'description', 'full', 'all')
search.ismatch('.*golden?rod.*', 'description', 'full', 'all')
search.ismatch('.*golden.?rod.*', 'description', 'full', 'all')
search.ismatch('.*golden\\ rod.*', 'description', 'full', 'all')


SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
.setFilter("search.ismatch('"golden rod"', 'description', 'full', 'all')");

This the sample index i created

{
  "@odata.context": "https://searchservicename.search.windows.net/indexes('index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 1,
      "HotelId": "3",
      "Description": "Motel 6 Golden"
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 1,
      "HotelId": "2",
      "Description": "Rodeway Inn"
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 1,
      "HotelId": "1",
      "Description": "Golden Rod Motel"
    }
  ]
}



// Define sample documents
        var documents = new List<SearchDocument>
        {
            new SearchDocument
            {
                { "HotelId", "1" },
                { "Description", "Golden Rod Motel" }
            },
            new SearchDocument
            {
                { "HotelId", "2" },
                { "Description", "Rodeway Inn" }
            },
            new SearchDocument
            {
                { "HotelId", "3" },
                { "Description", "Motel 6 Golden" }
            },
            // Add more sample documents as needed
        };


To search for multiple words with whitespace using Azure Cognitive Search filter with Lucene syntax, you can use the following approach:
   '\"golden rod\"', 'Description', 'full', 'all'

